# Sqoop import from db2 SQLException in nextKeyValue

Tags: hadoop, db2, sqoop

I'm trying to do a sqoop import from a db2 server.
My sqoop import is as below

```
sqoop import --fields-terminated-by '\001' --direct --connection-manager com.cloudera.sqoop.manager.Db2Manager --connect jdbc:db2://***.***.***:***/*** --username **** --password *** --query "select * FROM ZA1.RSR WHERE \$CONDITIONS"
```

When I'm running this query i am getting the following error

```
Error: java.io.IOException: SQLException in nextKeyValue
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBRecordReader.nextKeyValue(DBRecordReader.java:277)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.nextKeyValue(MapTask.java:556)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.MapContextImpl.nextKeyValue(MapContextImpl.java:80)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.WrappedMapper$Context.nextKeyValue(WrappedMapper.java:91)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:144)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AutoProgressMapper.run(AutoProgressMapper.java:64)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:787)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1714)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
  Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.SqlException: [jcc][t4][10199][10462][3.50.152] Required character converter is not available. ERRORCODE=-4220, SQLSTATE=null
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.wc.a(wc.java:55)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.wc.a(wc.java:119)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.bc.a(bc.java:1758)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.bc.n(bc.java:496)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.bc.F(bc.java:1263)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.jk.d(jk.java:939)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.jk.getString(jk.java:917)
    at org.apache.sqoop.lib.JdbcWritableBridge.readString(JdbcWritableBridge.java:71)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.lib.JdbcWritableBridge.readString(JdbcWritableBridge.java:61)
    at QueryResult.readFields(QueryResult.java:356)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBRecordReader.nextKeyValue(DBRecordReader.java:244)
```

Could you please help me out with this.

Answer (score 0):

This was a known fault in old Db2 jdbc driver versions.

You are using a very old (and out of support) JDBC 3.0 driver for Db2.  Your version is V9.5 fixpack 0 (driver identifies as 3.50.152).

Suggest you upgrade to a currently supported Db2 jdbc 4.0 driver, such as those supplied with Db2 Version 11.1, you can download these drivers for your platform from IBM fix central website after registering, or ask your Db2 DBA or onsite support person to upgrade the driver correctly for you.

Depending on your configuration, sometimes its possible to workaround this via java policy file changes on the client side to grant access to the sun.io package. But in general you will have fewer issues if you use a currently supported jdbc 4.0 driver with Db2 especially if you are using current client toolset versions.